# intent-filter with a url - how do we limit scope?

Tags: android

I wanted to use an intent-filter, such that if a user clicks a URL with a certain domain, they can view the url in my native app (if installed of course). So I have the intent filter looking like this:

```
<data android:host="www.mysite.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
```

is there a way to refine that rule to something like this:

```
<data android:host="www.mysite.com/farm" android:scheme="http"></data>
```

so, I don't want to open my app unless the url is using the subfolder "farm". If my app were to get called with just the plain domain, it would have nothing useful to do - it's only useful if the user is clicking a link pointing to the "farm" sub folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `android:pathPrefix` attribute of the [`android:data` element](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html).

Comment: I agree with Eric, please actually show the answer.  Obviously it isn't very descriptive in the APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You should use path parameter

```
  <data android:host="www.mysite.com"
        android:path="/farm"
        android:scheme="http" >
  </data>
```